# WizNet chip on Ethernet Shield oddly hot

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, hardware

I'm making a thermometer and, so I can graph the data, I have an Uno with the WizNet shield sending the data to a LAN ip. The chip itself is oddly hot, its temperature measures at around **110-120ºF** (43.33-48.89ºC). I want the program to be running almost 24/7. Is it okay for the chip to be this hot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [WizNet forums](http://wizwiki.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=2108&p=6933&hilit=w5100%20temperature#p6933) this is normal for these shields. Their justification being that it is a PHY and controller on a single chip. (Note this post only specifically mentions the W5100, which is among the more commonly used chips on these kinds of shields, however, I suspect that this is typical for most of the WizNet line, e.g. W5200 etc.)